# How do I assign named keys to arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert some python code to PHP, and I'm running into an issue with array keys.

My code is something like this:

```
<?php
$speciesarray = array("Amanita aprica"=>"species/Amanita_aprica.html",
    "Amanita augusta"=>"species/Amanita_augusta.html",
    "Amanita calyptratoides"=>"species/Amanita_calyptratoides.html",
    "Amanita calyptroderma"=>"species/Amanita_calyptroderma.html",
    "Amanita constricta"=>"species/Amanita_constricta.html",
    "Amanita gemmata"=>"species/Amanita_gemmata.html",
    "Amanita magniverrucata"=>"species/Amanita_magniverrucata.html",
    "Amanita muscaria"=>"species/Amanita_muscaria.html",
    "Amanita novinupta"=>"species/Amanita_novinupta.html",
    "Amanita ocreata"=>"species/Amanita_ocreata.html",
    "Amanita pachycolea"=>"species/Amanita_pachycolea.html",
    "Amanita pantherina"=>"species/Amanita_pantherina.html",
    "Amanita phalloides"=>"species/Amanita_phalloides.html",
    "Amanita porphyria"=>"species/Amanita_porphyria.html",
    "Amanita protecta"=>"species/Amanita_protecta.html",
    "Amanita pruittii"=>"species/Amanita_pruittii.html",
    "Amanita silvicola"=>"species/Amanita_silvicola.html",
    "Amanita smithiana"=>"species/Amanita_smithiana.html",
    "Amanita vaginata"=>"species/Amanita_vaginata.html",
    "Amanita velosa"=>"species/Amanita_velosa.html",
    "Amanita vernicoccora"=>"species/Amanita_vernicoccora.html");

shuffle($speciesarray); // Randomize the species array
$speciesarray = array_slice($speciesarray, 0, 5); // Select 5 elements from the randomized species array
reset($speciesarray);
$choice = key($speciesarray); // Get the first key from the reduced array
shuffle($speciesarray); // Randomize again

/* For debugging */
print_r($speciesarray);
echo("<br/>")
print_r($choice);
?>
```

Here's what I was expecting to see:

```
Array ( [Amanita silvicola] => species/Amanita_silvicola.html [Amanita gemmata] => species/Amanita_gemmata.html [Amanita calyptratoides] => species/Amanita_calyptratoides.html [Amanita vaginata] => species/Amanita_vaginata.html [Amanita phalloides] => species/Amanita_phalloides.html )
Amanita silvicola
```

And this is what I'm actually getting:

```
Array ( [0] => species/Amanita_silvicola.html [1] => species/Amanita_gemmata.html [2] => species/Amanita_calyptratoides.html [3] => species/Amanita_vaginata.html [4] => species/Amanita_phalloides.html )
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [php page on shuffle()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php):

> Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will
> remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just
> reordering the keys.

Also from that page is a user-contributed function to preserve keys in a shuffle:

```
<?php
    function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
        $keys = array_keys($array);

        shuffle($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $new[$key] = $array[$key];
        }

        $array = $new;

        return true;
    }
?>
```

On that same PHP page are many other user-contributed functions for this scenario

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `shuffle()` kills your named keys and it changes your array to a numeric indexed array. Therefore a better solution would be to shuffle only the array keys, select five of them and then select the values associated to the selected keys:

```php
$keys = array_keys( $speciesarray );
shuffle( $keys );
$keys = array_slice( $keys, 0, 5 );

$result = [];

foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
  $result[ $key ] = $speciesarray[ $key ];
}
```